# Set of pairs in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X_n$ be a set of pairs $(A,B)$ such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq \{\ 1 \dots n \}\ $

Determine $|X_n|$.

How I understand the problem:

$X_n$ is a set of pairs like $(a,b)$ but I'm lost at the part where it says $A \subseteq B$. Is $A$ a set? I thought $A$ was an element of a pair?

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Yes, here $A$ and $B$ are both *sets*, which together form a pair. The question is how many such pairs you can find.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Do you mean like they are multiplied such as $ \{\ 1,2,3 \}\ \times \{\ 2,3 \}\ = \{\ (1,2), (1,3), 2,2) \dots \}\ $ ?

Comment: No, not multiplication, just a pair. For example, if $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$ then the pair $(A, B)$ is $(\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3,4\})$. Note that this is a valid example for the case $n = 4$ (or higher $n$).

Comment: Would $2^n \cdot n!$ be the correct answer? As $B$ has to be fixed for $n$ and $A$ can be arranged into the powerset of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find pair of subsets of $\{1, \ldots n\}$ say $(A,B)$, such that $A \subseteq B$.

For example for $n = 2$ some possible pairs are $A = \{1\}$, $B = \{1,2\}$ or $A = \{2\}$, $B = \{2\}$ (Notice they can be the same).

**Hint** Fix $B$, let say it has $k$ elements, how many other $A$ will satisfy $A \subseteq B$? With that you should be able to count the pairs where $B$ has fixed size, and from that you should be able to count all possible pairs.

Comment: If $|B| = 3 $ then $A' = 2^3$ if we let $A'$ denote the possible sets of $A$, right?

Comment: Would $2^n \cdot n!$ be the correct answer? As $B$ has to be fixed for $n$ and $A$ can be arranged into the powerset of $n$.

Comment: @Paze No, but you got some things correct. For example if $|B| = k$, then you have $2^k$ possible $A$. But how many different $B$ of size $k$ are there? (Think of the binomial coefficient)

Comment: If $B$ was fixed size $k$ then there are $k!$ different $B$..? Can $B$ vary in size like $A$?

Ah, it can, let me calculate..

Comment: How about $2^n \cdot n! \cdot (n-1)! \cdots n$?

Because all the powersets $(A)$  of $B$ less than $n$ have already been counted, so I'm trying to say that $B$ can be any size $n$ or less and $A$ is any powerset of $n$.

Comment: Another try at a solution:

If $|B| = n$ then $B$ can be arranged into $2^n$ different sets. $A$ are all subsets of $B$ so the powerset would be $2^{2^n}$ = $4^n$ so $4^n \cdot 2^n = 2^{3n}$ ??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Without the need to fix a set size, you can do the following. Instead of looking at things from the sets' perspective, try looking at the problem from the numbers' perspective. For each number $i$ in $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, how many possibilities are there? In how many different "positions" can $i$ be?

> For example, it can be in $A$, but then it will have to be in $B$. Alternatively, it can be in $B$, but not $A$, i.e. in $B \backslash A$. Any other alternatives?

Then, the rest is pure combinatorics. What do you get as the result?

**Edit (more spoilers):**

> For each number $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ , there are 3 "boxes" in which it can go: into $A$, $B \backslash A$, or into none of them, say $S := \{1,2,\cdots,n\} \backslash B$. Thus, there are $3^n$ total choices to select the pair $(A, B)$.

Another way to think of this problem is writing a "word" of length $n$ using the letters $\{a, b, s\}$. The $i^{th}$ letter corresponds to which "box" the number $i$ goes into. (Having letter "a" means being in $A$ (thus readily in $B$), having letter "b" means being in $B$ but not $A$, and having letter $S$ means being in neither.) This forms a one-to-one correspondence with the pairs $\{A, B\}$. For example, the word "$ABASSB$" corresponds to the case that $A = \{1, 3\}, B =\{1, 2, 3, 6\}$. Clearly, there are $3^n$ such words.

Comment: Say $n=3$ then in my first pair I have $(3!,3!)$ different ways to order the pair, right? So I'd have $3! \cdot 3! $ ways to order the first pair. Am I warm?

Or if $ |B| = 3 $ I can say that $ |A| = 2^3 $...Hmm

Comment: Or if $ |B| = 3 $ I can say that $ A' = 2^3 $ if $A'$ denotes the possible sets of $A$..

Comment: @Paze You're warm with the 3, but not with the use of it.

Comment: What do you mean $B / A$ ? It sounds to me as if you mean that the numbers are either in A (and therefore $B$) or exclusively in $B$. They can appear in both in the same tuple as far as I know...?

Comment: @Paze By $B \backslash A$, I mean their set difference, so elements there are "exclusively in B", as you say.

Comment: Another try at a solution:

If $|B| = n$ then $B$ can be arranged into $2^n$ different sets. $A$ are all subsets of $B$ so the powerset would be $2^{2^n}$ = $4^n$ so $4^n \cdot 2^n = 2^{3n}$ ??

Comment: The number 3 is there at least, lol...Please tell me this is correct..